# How do I change my dates dynamically on the browser?

Tags: html, jquery, regex

I have a jQuery with a regex that replaces the dates that have slashes with periods and removes the time stamp but keeps the date, but it is not reflecting on the web browser. How do I dynamically change the date and reflect the results on the browser? Any help is welcomed :)

```js
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var oldText = $(this).text();
    var newText = oldText.replace(new RegExp("<td.*?>([0-3]?[0-9])\/([0-3]?[0-9])\/((?:[0-9]{2})?[0-9]{2}).*?<\/td>","g"), "$1.$2.$3");
 
});
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td class="test">9/2/2021 10:59:15 AM</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="test">12/15/2015 12:10:45 PM</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="test">10/10/2012 5:00:10 AM</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You are returning the replacement on `$(document).ready` but if you want to update a certain element value with the replacement you should set it to that instead of returning.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thank you for the reply. Not sure what you mean updating a certain element value with the replacement

Comment: Your replacement works, and is in the variable `newText` What do you want to do with the value of that variable?

Comment: what I'm wanting to do with is return the replaced regex and have it reflect on the browser

Comment: What I mean is that you should set the replacement to where you want to see it, an element value, the body of the document perhaps. Or get just the table `<td>` 's that you want first and then replace those values. You can check out the posted pattern of sln to keep the existing `<td.*?>` as right now they will disapear as they are matched and not part of the replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to parse HTML with regex, then you should query for the relevant HTML elements, and update their texts:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.test').text(function(index, oldText) {
    return oldText.replace(/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+).*/, '$1.$2.$3');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is there a way to replace it with <td.*?>([0-3]?[0-9])\/([0-3]?[0-9])\/((?:[0-9]{2})?[0-9]{2}).*?<\/td> instead of using .test. I'm wanting it to completely remove the time stamp but keep the date in period format

Comment: You cannot parse HTML with regex see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Andreas! Didn’t realize that you can’t parse html like that but this will do

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to replace with the stuff in the begging and end as well.

`(<td.*?>)([0-3]?[0-9])\/([0-3]?[0-9])\/((?:[0-9]{2})?[0-9]{2})(.*?<\/td>)`

replace `$1$2.$3.$4$5`

https://regex101.com/r/zrE2eh/1

You can use a variable look behind and ahead as well if you need to keep it to
the 1/2/3 capture groups as well.

`(?<=<td.*?>)([0-3]?[0-9])\/([0-3]?[0-9])\/((?:[0-9]{2})?[0-9]{2})(?=.*?<\/td>)`

Replace `$1.$2.$3`
https://regex101.com/r/OOJP7t/1

Comment: I'm needing assistance with the jquery to reflect my regex change on the browser so it displays the change

Comment: yes I need a regex to parse the HTML :)

Comment: @user3683976 Then you should specifically say that and exclude any dom functional interface. I was downvoted by somebody who doesn't know the difference and who has it brainwashed the opinion that html can't be parsed with regex. I'm here to tell you I do it all the time.

Comment: How would you then parse the HTML with jquery?